# How to add telescope functionality in any project?

Tags: meteor, telescope

I want to use telescope in my meteor app.
How can I use only some of it's functionality in My meteor app.
When I add package my app got crash.

I add some packages in my packages in my package file in .meteor.

```
############ Telescope Core ############

telescope:core
```

Answer (score 0):

Telescope does not quite support being dropped in into another Meteor app yet, sorry. You can check the [sample project](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/sample-project) to see what a full Telescope repo looks like.

Comment: Thanks For it @Sacha, 
It's means i cant' use any functionality like searching top bar etc in my project.